# How do I get HTML form to submit to CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now and haven't been able to find a good working solution.

I need 100 people to sit down one at a time at one computer, and fill out the form I made, every time someone hits submit, I want that information to be saved in a CSV. I want all 100 people's submissions to be in one single CSV file. What would be the easiest way to make this happen?

Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: what have you done so far ? Please share your attempt's code.

Comment: you submit to a php file that will add a line to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best idea is to use a database you can use sql or nonsql and than convert it to csv there is a lot of online service that can convert it for free